# Which is the better syntax for referencing elements of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I want to refer to elements of an infinite sequence $a_{i}\in A$ having indexes greater than 3, which is the better syntax?

1. $(a_{i})_{(i> 3)}$
2. $a_{(i> 3)}$

It seems to me that (1) could refer to a sub sequence comprised only of these elements, while (2) might be used to refer to any particular element.  For example:

$\forall (a_{i})_{(i> 3)}$

as opposed to

$\exists a_{(i> 3)}$

Comment: I would define the set $V = \{a_i \in A | i >3\}$ and then just refer to $V$.

Comment: I guess it depends on the context or how you're trying to use it, but I would use a different variable to represent the subset where $i>3$

Comment: I need to refer to several different "classes" of elements within several different sequences.

Comment: I would definitely read option (1.) as a subsequence, so I don't think it is a good solution. I'd second rpa's proposal.

Comment: My problem with rpa's suggestion is that $V$ is a set, and the elements of $A$ are are not necessarily unique.  From the definition of a sequence: "In mathematics, a sequence is an enumerated collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed. Like a set, it contains members (also called elements, or terms). The number of elements (possibly infinite) is called the length of the sequence. Unlike a set, the same elements can appear multiple times at different positions in a sequence, and order matters."  So, I don't see how this is a viable option.

Comment: If that’s your concern you could define a new sequence (not set) $b_i=a_{i+3}$ for $i=1,2,\dots$ though that could get a little confusing